# Is it possible to add an operator-overloading extension function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I mean something like this:

```
fun operator Table.get(column_name: String) = this.column(column_name)
// Currently gives an error: "Expecting a top level declaration"
```

`Table` instance currently works like: `table.column("column_name")`

I want to make it work like this: `table["column_name"]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is possible, it's just that the `operator` keyword has go before the `fun` keyword in the declaration (as do other modifiers, such as `infix`, `inline`, etc.):

```
operator fun Table.get(column_name: String) = this.column(column_name)
```